# How do graphic file format types work?

Tags: graphics, png, file-format

I'm very interested in understanding how graphic file format (PNG, JPG, GIF) work. Are there any code examples that demonstrate how these files are made and also how they are interpreted (viewed in browser)?

Comment: As I see the discussion below, I don't think you were asking the right question. You should explain your exact need more directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of which graphic file format you are working with, you need to understand the basic nature that all graphic files have in common.

- File Header

  1. File Type, Version, (Time & Date Stamp - if included)
  2. Possible data structure/s info or chunks
  3. Flags for which color type to be expected, if compression is available and which type, byte order (endian), has transparency, and other various flags.
- Image Data Info

  1. Width  normally in pixels sometimes in pels, bits or bytes
  2. Height normally in pixels sometimes in pels, bits or bytes
  3. Bits Per Pixel or Pixel Depth
  4. Image Size in Bytes: numPixelsWidth * numPixelsHeight * ((bits or bytes) for each pixel)
  5. Color Type: - Each Pixel has color data which can vary

     - Gray Scale
     - Palette
     - Color RGB
     - Color RGBA
     - Possible Others
- If Compression Is Present Which Coding and Encoding Is Used
- The actual image data

Once you understand this basic structure then parsing image files becomes easier once you know the specification to the file structure you are working with. When you know how many bytes to read in to your file pointer that includes all headers and chunks, then you can advance your file pointer to the data structure that will read in or write out all the pixel (color) data. In many cases the pixel data is usually 24bits per pixel such that each channel RGBA - Red, Green, Blue, and Alpha are 8bits each or one byte same as an unsigned char. This is represented in either a structure or a two dimensional array. Either way once you know the file's structure and know how to read in the actual image or color data you can easily store it into a single array. Then what you do with it from there depends on your application's needs.

Answer (score 0):

The most detailed information can be obtained by reading the file format specification and implementing a parser in the language you know best.

A good way would be to read the format and transform it into an array of four byte tupples (RGBA, the red, green, blue and alpha parts of a color) This will allow you to use this format as an in between format between formats for easy conversion. At the same time most APIs support the displaying of this raw format.

A good format to get started with is [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format). As old as it is, if this is your first encounter with writing a parser this is a safe an 'easy' format. A good second format is [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics). Start with the uncompressed variations and later add the compression.

Next step is TGA to learn reading chunks or JPG to learn more about compression.

Extra tip: Some implementations of writers contain(ed) errors causing images to be in violation of the format. Others added extra features that never made it to the official specs. When writing a parser this can be a real pain. When you are running into problems always second guess the image you are trying to read. A good binary/hex file reader/editor can be a very helpful tool. I used AXE, if I remember correctly it allows you to overlay the hex codes with a format so you can quickly recognize the header and chunks.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Do you have any experience in creating your own custom file format? If so, what does this entail?

Comment: @user3647894 - all I ever did was create XML or ini files with extra data that accompanied one or more graphic files. I put them in a folder hierarchy and zipped them. By sticking to existing formats you can still use existing graphics software which is a huge advantage. The xml/ini files would contain frame data for spritesheets or other meta data.

Comment: Very interesting. Now is there a way to use an existing file type, such as PNG, but to add data to the image? For instance, if I wanted a native PNG to automatically show a blue hue on a normal PNG photo?

Comment: @user3647894 - To show a blue hue is not a feature of the format but of the program that shows the image. If you are interested in that you might want to have a look at developing filters for painting programs. Paint.NET is very easy to extend with custom filters. Some file formats allow you to add extra data to a file so you can add things like copyright, text etc. Be careful though some painting programs do not understand these extra bits and will strip them out.